# HTTP iFrame blank in HTTPS page

Tags: javascript, html, http, iframe, https

Please help me!

I've installed SSL certificate on my server and now can't access on "mixed contents" anymore. My actual problem is an iFrame widget which is HTTP only:

```
<iframe src="http://www.exchangerates.org.uk/widget/ER-LRTICKER.php?w=435&s=1&mc=USD&mbg=FFFFFF&bs=no&bc=000044&f=verdana&fs=10px&fc=555555&lc=597384&lhc=FF8201&vc=FF8201&vcu=008000&vcd=FF0000&" width="435" height="30" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0"></iframe>
```

The result is that I get the content blocked (blank on page) on both Firefox and IE.
Is there any workaround? But please just don't tell me to change browser settings since my users are **not** going to do so.
Thanks in advance for your attention!

Comment: Cant you change it to the `https` protocol?

Comment: Yes I tried and it works but widget is not properly working. It's a slider with Forex rates quotes, but unfortunately it doesn't move with HTTPS protocol and it only shows 3 items on 2 lines instead of 1 only. Definitely not working with HTTPS ha!

Comment: Keep in mind that any dependency within your code should be HTTPS aswel if you are using a HTTPS connection.

Comment: I know that already but that's the only good widget over the web, I can't stick to another one even using HTTPS protocol. So, no way to bypass the warning and show the content? Still from the code and not browser settings.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution (for you) is to have the 3rd party supply a SSL/TLS URL.

If that however is not possible you are out of luck (with only frontend languages as tagged on your question).

If you are also running a backend language though you could proxy the iframe URL and provide the proxied URL in your iframe e.g. `https://yourdomain.com/exchangerates` which retrieves the page (including the resources used).

Another option would be to see whether the site has an API so you can download the data you need so that you can display the data on a page you control yourself.

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate but luckily I already fixed it by myself!